# Est-ce que la signification du mot "homophobe" est aujourd'hui altérée?

Tags: étymologie, évolution, définition

D'après "Internet", le suffixe phobe signifie:

> avoir peur de, ne pas aimer

Plus précisément, d'après wiktionnaire:

> Élément qui signifie « qui craint » ou « qui déteste »,

Or, d'après Larousse, le mot homophobe signifie:

> Qui est hostile à l'homosexualité, aux homosexuels : Législation
>   homophobe.

Cependant, on peut ne pas aimer quelque chose sans être hostile à ladite chose.

De plus, d'autres mots finissant par le suffixe `phobe` gardent la signification originale du suffixe, comme:

---

**Agoraphobe** (d'après larousse)

> Phobie des espaces découverts (places) et des lieux publics.

Les personnes agoraphobes ne montrent pas d'hostilité envers la foule, elles en ont peur.

---

**Arachnophobe** (d'après wiktionnaire)

> Qui a peur des araignées.

Une personne arachnophobe ne montre pas d'hostilité envers les araignées, elles en ont peur.

---

Ma question est donc la suivante: Est-ce que la signification du mot homophobe est aujourd'hui biaisée? Si oui, quelles en sont les causes?

Comment: "altérée" par rapport à quoi ? qui a changé dans le temps, ou qui n'est pas étymologique ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le [suffixe -phobe](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-phobe) a plusieurs sens différents, et ce n'est pas nouveau.

Il y a un sens plus proche de la racine grecque qui est la crainte, la terreur. C'est le sens que l'on trouve dans des termes scientifiques comme [*hydrophobe*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hydrophobe), [*photophobe*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/photophobe), attesté en médecine et en biologie dès le début du 19<sup>e</sup>, ou [*agoraphobe*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/agoraphobe), attesté en psychologie à la fin du 19<sup>e</sup>.

On peut noter que le sens originel d'*hydrophobie* dévie déjà de ce sens étymologique.
Ce sens, déjà présent en bas latin sous la forme *hydrophobus*, désigne une [phase de la rage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rage_(maladie)#Forme_furieuse) où la déglutition de liquides entraîne des spasmes. Il ne s'agit pas d'une crainte de l'eau, mais d'un rejet de l'eau pour des raisons physiologiques.

Ce sens dépasse le sens étymologique dans l'usage scientifique. Ainsi, en chimie, un produit [*hydrophobe*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrophobie_(physique)) a tendance à rejeter l'eau. Il ne s'agit évidemment pas de crainte, mais d'un phénomène physique.

Il y a un autre sens qui est la haine, le rejet, qui date (au moins) du début du 19<sup>e</sup> siècle, et qui est utilisé en sociologie et en politique. Ainsi [*androphobe*](https://www.littre.org/definition/androphobe) et [*anthropophobe*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/anthopophobe) sont utilisés au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle comme synonymes de *misandre* et *misanthrope*. Le premier mot utilisant ce sens de -phobe a rentrer dans l'usage courant est semble-t-il [*xénophobe*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/x%C3%A9nophobe), au début du 20<sup>e</sup> siécle, “probablement créé par [Anatole France](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatole_France) à propos de l'[affaire Dreyfus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affaire_Dreyfus)”.

Les trois sens sont productifs en français moderne. Dans le sens de crainte, on parle d'[*agoraphobie*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/agoraphobie), de [*cancérophobie*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/canc%C3%A9rophobie), de [*téléphonophobie*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/t%C3%A9l%C3%A9phonophobie), etc. Le mot [*phobie*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/phobie) seul a aussi ce sens. En chimie, on parle de produit [*oléophobe*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ol%C3%A9ophobe), etc. Dans le sens de haine, on parle de [*francophobie*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/francophobie), de [*judéophobie*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jud%C3%A9ophobie) (les nuances avec [*antisémitisme*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antis%C3%A9mitisme) pourraient faire et on fait l'objet de nombreux articles), d'[*islamophobie*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/islamophobie), d'[*homophobie*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophobie), de [*transphobie*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transphobie), etc.

Réduire *-phobe* à « craindre » consiste donc à ne regarder qu'un des sens du suffixe, qui est le sens grec mais pas le premier sens à être passé en français. Quant à lui donner un sens de « ne pas aimer », c'est plutôt un contresens : *-phobe* ne veut à peu près jamais dire « n'aimant pas ». Une phobie signifie que l'on a peur, pas que l'on n'aime pas. Un arachnophobe peut paniquer à l'idée de toucher une araignée tout en aimant qu'elle le débarasse des insectes nuisibles. Les composés comme *xénophobe*, *homophobe*, etc. signifient non pas que l'on n'aime pas certaines personnes, mais qu'on rejette leur participation à la société. Il n'y a en fait qu'en chimie que *-phobe* est antonyme de *-phile*.

Contester un mot comme *homophobe* parce qu'il n'aurait pas le « bon » sens, ou prétendre qu'il a un sens différent, manifeste au mieux d'une ignorance de la langue, et au pire est un amalgame délibéré entre ne pas aimer et ne pas respecter. Quelqu'un qui revendique le droit à la X-phobie « parce qu'on ne peut pas m'obliger à choisir ce que j'aime » pratique la confusion entre absence d'amour et haine. Ne pas être X-phobe, c'est accepter que X fasse partie de la société comme non-X, cela n'a rien à voir avec *aimer* dans ses différents sens.

L'amalgame entre les sens de *-phobe* n'est certes pas nouveau. [Joseph de Maistre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_de_Maistre) voyait il a deux siècles dans les philosophes agnostiques ou athées, ou à vrai dire séculaires, de la [*théophobie*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=M4APAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA158&dq=%22+je+l%27appelle+la+th%C3%A9ophobie%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiipejQpIjkAhUBrxoKHVE9BgMQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22%20je%20l'appelle%20la%20th%C3%A9ophobie%22&f=false) — assimilant un choix philosophique qu'il désapprouve à une maladie. Mais il y a une grande différence entre un comportement psychologique ou physiologique comme l'agoraphobie ou l'arachnophobie, et un choix philosophique ou politique comme la xénophobie ou l'homophobie.

Comment: Superbe explication, merci! J'en conclu donc que le mot homophobe a une signification bien spécifique, qui n'a pas changé, mais qu'il est plutôt mal utilisé.

Answer (score 8):

Le suffixe *-phobe* « exprime l'aversion instinctive, l'hostilité irraisonnée ou parfois l'absence d'affinité vis-à-vis de quelqu'un ou de quelque chose » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-phobe)) ; son sens primaire en grec antique « peur morbide, crainte » revêt un intérêt étymologique mais n'est par déterminant. Comme le dit [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-phobe), le suffixe « sert à former des adjectifs ou des noms qui définissent un individu qui manifeste cette haine ou cette peur. ». On peut noter au passage que *détester* implique une aversion que *ne pas aimer* ne signifie pas. Au *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (chez *Robert*, sup. A. Rey) on dit essentiellement qu'*homophobe* (1979), adjectif et nom, est un composé de *homo* pour « homosexuel masculin », qui « exprime la résistance du rejet traditionnel de l'homosexualité par les hétérosexuels intolérants ».

Avec des personnes représentées par le premier élément, comme dans *francophobe* par exemple, on n'a pas uniquement celui qui n'aime pas la France, les Français mais bien aussi celui qui témoigne d'une aversion ou d'une hostilité à leur égard ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-phobe)). Dans *agoraphobe* ou *arachnophobe*, le premier élément désigne une chose et non une personne ou un groupe (les *homosexuels*) comme précédemment. Par ailleurs, on a bien des termes avec *-phobe* où l'on peut difficilement dire que le suffixe conserve son sens de *peur*, comme *calciphobe*, d'une plante « qui ne pousse pas dans un sol calcaire » (TLFi) etc. On notera enfin l'existence d'*androphobe*, [didactique](https://www.littre.org/definition/androphobe), pour *celui/celle qui craint/fuit les hommes* (personne de sexe masculin) et de l'*anthropophobe*, synonyme de *misanthrope* (TLFi).

---

Donc **non**, pas plus (« altérée ») qu'avec les autres mots où le premier élément désigne des (groupes) personnes (*anglophobe, germanophobe, judéophobe, xénophobe* etc.) où l'on a au moins un exemple (*francophobe*) où le sens du suffixe peut aller beaucoup plus loin que « ne pas aimer » pour inclure l'*hostilité* dont la définition en question fait état.

Answer (score -2):

Le mot « homophobe » est de très récente origine (pas dans le TLFi) et il a été conçu pour signifier ce qu'il signifie aujourd'hui ; cette  conception n'a cependant pas été faite avec un soin extrême. On aurait dû choisir une combinaison utilisant le préfixe « miso », qui exprime clairement la haine ; seulement on a voulu à tout prix que « homosexuel » figure, tout au moins en partie dans le mot.  À mon avis une combinaison comme « misohomosexuel » aurait été suffisamment exacte, mais la succession particulière de son dans un tel mot aura probablement fait reculer ceux qui ont choisi le terme. De plus il est probable que c'est un terme calqué sur l'anglais ;

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophobia#Origin_of_the_term) Coined by George Weinberg, a psychologist, in the 1960s,[13] the term homophobia is a blend of (1) the word homosexual, itself a mix of neo-classical morphemes, and (2) phobia from the Greek φόβος, phóbos, meaning "fear", "morbid fear" or "aversion".[14][15][16] Weinberg is credited as the first person to have used the term in speech.[12] The word homophobia first appeared in print in an article written for the May 23, 1969, edition of the American pornographic magazine Screw, in which the word was used to refer to heterosexual men's fear that others might think they are gay.

De ce fait personne ne s'est occupé de rester fidèle au principes de la formation des mots en français. La formation du mot en anglais n'est pas elle-même très exacte.

Il est évident que l'on devrait avoir un terme selon le modèle de « misanthrope » et « misogyne ».

Comment: *anthropophobie* a été un temps synonyme de *misanthrope*, mais est tombé en désuétude. Le suffixe anglais *-phobia* a les mêmes sens que le suffixe français *-phobie*, il n'y aurait donc eu aucune raison de traduire *homophobia* différemment. La formation anglaise est tout à fait logique du point de vue du suffixe : *-phobia* comme *-phobie* ne se limite pas à la crainte. Les « évidences » que tu énonces ne sont que des opinions personnelles que l'histoire de la langue dément.

Comment: @Gilles On ne peut pas dire que les définitions soient consistantes : d'un côté on a « germanophobie : haine des allemands », de l'autre « anglophobie : aversion pour le peuple anglais » ; d'autre part il y a le préfixe « mis-o » qui de façon caractéristique spécifie la haine, alors que « -phobe » se limite à la peur, l'aversion, cette dernière n'entrainant pas automatiquement la haine, laquelle se traduit par l'acte. Il est incontestable que l'emploi de « homophobe» est associé à des actes  agressifs et non préservatifs. Je crois toujours que le choix n'est pas bon, (champ 1/2)

Comment: @Gilles et le suffixe « phobe » penche trop du côté de la peur, de la simple aversion, de l'idée de ce qui répulsif. « homophobe » même un terme pernicieux en cela que l'on s'en sert, consciemment ou non, pour culpabiliser une aversion naturelle. (champ 2/2)

Comment: Merci pour la citation.  Le reste de la réponse est complètement farfelu !

Comment: @petitrien Gardez vos mercis d'hypocrite et vos communications barbares pour vous !